# Does rsync "know" to avoid encrypting a payload when not needed?

Tags: rsync

Is rsync designed to **not use encryption**, when **not moving data across the network**?  For example from USB device to HD on the same device.

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` doesn't implement encryption at all.

The `ssh` transport that can be used to a remote system will provide an encrypted transport in that scenario. Notice that per my opening sentence a network connection directly to a true `rsync` daemon is (also) *not encrypted*.

And to answer your question explicitly, `rsync` does not encrypt data when copying from a local source to a local destination.